# Primitive of $\frac{1}{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I want show that the function $w: \mathbb{C}^{*} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ determine by:
$$ w(z) = \frac{1}{z} $$
Hasn't a primitive function defined in $\mathbb{C}^{*}$, I have a primitive function of $w(z)$ for the set $\mathbb{C}^{-} = { z \in \mathbb{C}-(-\infty, 0]}$, but I don't know how I could proceed.

Thank you.

Comment: The integral of $w(z)$ over the unit circle is non-zero.

Comment: I forgot to say that I don't know anything about complex integration, sorry.

Comment: Morera's theorem.

Comment: Related: [Why does $z^{-1}$ not have an anti derivative?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1756666), though maybe not definitively helpful since you don't know complex integration. Here, it would help if you'd say where the problem arises (and particularly, what tools you might have available).

Comment: What do you mean by "I have a primitive function of $w(z)$ for.."? What is this function? Is this a part of a problem you are solving? Please provide the information.

Comment: I have knowledge about power series and your properties, holomorphic functions. I can construct a analytic funcion $f$ defined in $\mathbb{C}^{-}$ such that $ f'(z) = \frac{1}{z}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Andrew D. Hwang says, this is hard to answer when we don't know what tools are available to you, since you have rejected the obvious choice. But I will assume you at least know that the only primitives of $w(z) = 0$ on a region (which is connected by definition) are constants.

Now consider that primitive you have on $\Bbb C^-$, which we refer to as $\ln z$. Suppose that you have a function $f$ on $\Bbb C^*$ with $f'(z) = 1/z$ for $z \in \Bbb C^-$. Then we can define $g(z) = f(z) - \ln z$ on $\Bbb C^-$ and discover that $g'(z) = 1/z - 1/z = 0$. I.e., $g$ is a primitive of $0$ and is therefore some constant $C$. So $f(z) = \ln z + C$ for some $C$. But $$\lim_{\theta \to \pi} f(e^{i\theta}) = C + i\pi \ne C - i\pi=\lim_{\theta \to -\pi} f(e^{i\theta})$$ while $$\lim_{\theta \to \pi} e^{i\theta} = -1=\lim_{\theta \to -\pi} e^{i\theta}$$
So $f$ cannot be continuous at $-1$, which means it cannot be analytic on $\Bbb C^*$.