# The Complex Log Function

Tags: complex-analysis

Will trying to integrate $\int \frac{1}{z-z_0}$ over $|z-z_0|=r$

I have tried to look for an antiderivative and was asked to point out where it is not defined.

So the antiderivative is $ln(z-z_0)$

1. If I look at the log function over the $\mathbb{R}$ the function is not defined in $(-\infty,0]$ so in my case the function is not defined at $(-\infty+z_0,z_0]$?
2. If I look at the log function over the $\mathbb{C}$ log is defined as $ln(z-z_0)=ln|z-z_0|+iArg(z-z_0)$ where is it not defined?
3. in general how does the complex log function look?

Comment: This point should be explained in **every** single textbook on complex analysis and be covered in **every** course on the subject. How does it get to be a question?!

Comment: For 3, perhaps see [Why does $z^{−1}$ not have an anti derivative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1756666)

Answer (score 1):

That integral is equal to $2\pi i$, because\begin{align*}\int_{|z-z_0|=r}\frac1{z-z_0}\,dz&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{(z_0+e^{it})'}{z_+e^{it}-z_0}\,dt\\&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{ie^{it}}{e^{it}}\,dt\\&=\int_0^{2\pi}i\,dt\\&=2\pi i.\end{align*}So, you can deduce that the function that you were trying to integrate *has no primitive*, because if it had a primitive $F$, then$$\int_{|z-z_0|=r}\frac1{z-z_0}\,dz=F\bigl(e^{2\pi i}\bigr)-F(e^0)=0.$$

There is no differentiable (or even continuous) $\log$ function from $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ into $\mathbb C$. Because if there was, its derivative would be $\frac1z$ and, by the same argument as above, this function has no primitive.