# What's wrong with this "proof" that the (contour) integral of the function $f(z)=1/z$ over a circle centered at the origin is $0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, fake-proofs

I'm currently self-studying complex analysis, and I've arrived at the following conundrum:

Let $f(z)=1/z$, and let $C$ denote the circle of radius of $1$ centered at the origin. Then consider the integral $\oint_{C}{f(z)dz}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\frac{ie^{i\theta}d\theta}{e^{i\theta}}}$.

On the one hand, cancelling the $e^{i\theta}$ terms leaves $\int_{0}^{2\pi}{i}=2\pi i$, which makes sense because $f$ has a simple pole with residue $1$ at $z=0$.

But on the other hand, if we make the substitution $u=e^{i\theta}$, we then get $\int_{1}^{1}{\frac{du}{u}}=0$. This answer seems like nonsense, but it's not clear to me what exactly went wrong. Any efforts to help clear this up for me would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Related: [Why does $z^{−1}$ not have an anti derivative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1756666)

Comment: The integral $\int_\gamma z^{-1}$ is not independent of the path $\gamma$.

Comment: Did you check the requirements for a substitution? You have to make some assumptions on your function u which will prohibit substitution in this case.

Comment: One suggestion: try the same while integrating sin(x) from 0 to pi and substituting sin(x)=u. You will get the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider $u=e^{i\theta}$, the variable $u$ now takes complex value so the integrand $f(u)$ is no longer a complex-valued function of a **real** variable. The integral becomes a line-integral with starting point = end point, and, in general, such a line-integral not just depends on its starting point and end point (here, they are (1,0)).