# Confused on evaluating line integral with parameterization

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, line-integrals

Consider the given line integral below:

$$I=\oint_C \frac{dz}{z-3}$$

Here, $C$ is the circle $|z-2|=5$

The question is:

> 1. Determine whether $\displaystyle\oint_C \dfrac{dz}{z-3}=0$
> 2. Does your answer to Number 1. Contradict Cauchy's (Cauchy-Goursat) Theorem?

Actually i'm on chapter Complex Line Integral, so i **can't** use Cauchy's Integral Formula or Residual Theorem in my work bcz they haven't yet been introduced. Permissible thing is using Cauchy-Goursat Theorem that is

> if $f(z)$ is analytic in a region $R$ and on its boundary $C$. Then
>   $$\oint_C f(z)\,\mathbb dz=0$$

My attemp :

Actually i don't have an idea how to integrate it with parametrization. The last time i integrated complex line integral in another question, my answer was said to be wrong bcz of i didn't consider the branch point or something.

At least i'm trying, here is my work:

If $|z-2|=5\Rightarrow z=2+5e^{i\theta}$, then $\mathbb dz=5ie^{i\theta}\,\mathbb d \theta$

$$\begin{align}
I&=\oint_C \frac{dz}{z-3}\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{5ie^{i\theta}}{5e^{i\theta}-1}\,\mathbb d \theta\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{i}{5e^{i\theta}-1}\,\mathbb d\theta+\int_0^{2\pi} i\,\mathbb d\theta \tag{By Long Divison}\\
&=\int_5^5 \frac{\mathbb du}{(u-1)u}+\int_0^{2\pi} i\,\mathbb d\theta \tag{By U-Substitution}\\
&=0+2\pi i \tag{i'm not sure here}\\
&=2\pi i
\end{align}
$$

The reason i'm using long division is to avoid $0$, bcz when i directly using u-substitution, whatever the integrand is, i have an inteval $5\leq u\leq 5$ which is the result will gives me $0$ isn't it?

Then i check on my Solution Manual Book, the answer is $0$ (it's strange), bcz the function has singularity and the singularity causes it fails to be analytic in a certain point.

What is actually the answer for my problem. And even if I tried to deviate the rules and use The Residual Theorem:

$$\underset{z=3}{\operatorname{Res}}\,\frac{1}{z-3}=1$$

$1$ is in $C$, Then i have

$$\displaystyle\oint_C \dfrac{dz}{z-3}=2\pi i$$

In short, my answer is contradict $$\displaystyle\oint_C \dfrac{dz}{z-3}=0$$
Besides, my solution manual gives me the line integral is $0$. Which one is true? Is my Solution Manual Book wrong? Or mine?
Where is my mistakes? Is my answer contradict with Cauchy's Theorem? Why?

Please give me the best explanation. Especially, why does if i'm not using long division, the line integral is $0$, but **with** long division it gives me $2\pi i$?

Many thanks for you if you wanna help me.

Comment: The correct answer is $2\pi i$. This does not contradict the Gauchy-Goursat theorem because the integrand $\frac{1}{z-3}$ is not analytic in the region under consideration, namely the disk $D_5(2)$. Indeed, it has a (simple) pole at $z=3$.

Comment: The integral is $2\pi i$  I don't see how they get $0$.

Comment: Actually, could you explain to me how to solve this using "parameterization only"? Without any theorem, i can't really understand

Comment: @saulspatz They, (in my Solution Manual) considering there is no rule. After that, they just use U-Substituion without doing the long division, considering $0$ and $2\pi$ is the same thing when we plug it into $e^{i\theta}$, it wil gives $0$.. or not? I'm not sure, but that is their answer in my Solution manual. So my solution is wrong then?

Comment: Your solution looks right to me.

Comment: @saulspatz wait. Then, it has 2 answer? $0$ and $2\pi i$? I don't get it. Sorry

Comment: Nobody here has said that $0$ is the correct answer.  Where are you getting this?  The answer is $2\pi i$.

Comment: What's the name of the book?

Comment: As i said before, when directly i use the u-substitition, it will gives me $0$. Actually i just want to know how to integrate this line integral with parameterization. Could you help me? I just feel afraid if i found the contradiction.

Comment: @sav Schaum's Outline, Complex Variables. Actually i'm using Chegg for my solution manual. Thanks

Comment: This one https://books.google.com.au/books?id=EjT3fE2SgGwC&printsec=frontcover&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false

Which chapter/question number?

Comment: @sav in chapter 4 number 4.62. Many thanks for you by the way ..

Comment: you should be careful when using familiar u-substitution from real analysis in the complex case: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2355151/whats-wrong-with-this-proof-that-the-contour-integral-of-the-function-fz?rq=1

Comment: @peek-a-boo Well, i think i get it know. What i've learned from ur link is, $z^{-1}$ doesn't have an anti-derivative. So, i can't solve this with find the anti-derivative right? And when i do the u-subs, i just using the local primitive not a global primitive (Even if i don't know what they are, please explain to me) Then how. Sadly, i can't use Cauchy's Integral Formula, and Residue Theorem. The main of my question is just how to calculate this integral with parametrization?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cauchy Goursat in the region $R=\{3\}^c$ to show that $\int_C {dz \over z-3} = \int_D{dz \over z-3} $, where $D$ is the curve $t \mapsto 3+e^{it}$, and it is straightforward to evaluate this integral and see that it is non zero.

Comment: One quick question, why do we have to change the region? Is that mean, Cauchy Goursat just works on curve that match with the curve? In this case, the function $z=3+e^{i\theta}$ and we have to change the region into $R=\{3\}^c$ as you said?

Comment: You can use Cauchy Goursat to show that the two integrals have the same value, and the second one is simpler to evaluate.