# Understanding branch cut of logarithm function (pg-99 of VCA)

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

> [image]
>
> Page-99 , VCA by Tristan Needham

In this page, it is shown how as we circular about the circle $\omega$ moves to different points. I am struggling to understand how the curve bends when moving. Could someone explain that?

Comment: Does this [picture of the Riemann surface of log](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EJyQc.png) (taken from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1756666/why-does-z-1-not-have-an-anti-derivative)) help?

Comment: You should add the paragraph that you got confused so that other people can undersstand the context of what you're asking. @Wave

Comment: In your question, you seem to be taking two branches. I tried checking that section and he works it out for only one branch to my understanding. Are you referencing multipile pages or only the one which pic comes in

Comment: @Aplateofmomos I added the paragraph. Why do you think is he only taking one branch I mean if he add $+2\pi i$ doesn't need to take another branch?

Comment: Ok, so you are saying the function switches over to two different branches depending on motion?

Comment: @Aplateofmomos Hmm I don't really understand your rephrased scentense because of my english but i think so. I mean if we takes the natural branch of logarithm to compute $\log(z)$ then why did he add $2\pi i$? I thought that he looks at $\log(z)$ in the "next" branch.

Comment: I mean for comparing such branches you need to actually have a branch cut. Till the point you have said, he hasn't even made a cut yet to my understanding @Wave

Comment: @Aplateofmomos but what is a branchcut? Maybe that's also a missunderstanding.

Comment: I have written about it a bit in my answer. Maybe that will help. Let me know if it does @Wave

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136727/discussion-between-wave-and-a-plate-of-momos).

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang so is your picture the picture of the logarithm function viewed as multivalued function?

Comment: In a word, _yes_. Precisely, it's the sum of the real and imaginary parts, which shows both the undefinedness at $0$ and the multi-valued nature.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Perfect thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't try and give some calculation with number but rather a qualitative answer for you. I'll show how to "see" the situation qualitatively for the counter-clockwise motion.

Firstly notice that if you were to move around the circle counter-clockwise, initially the magnitude of $|z|$ is decreasing as the point on circle is closer and closer to origin and later after the redpoint I marked here, it will increase again:

> [image]

What about the angle? Well if you were initially at $\theta$, as you spin around the circle, you gain more and more angle till you return to the initial point where you have total $2\pi$ more angle. That why the curve is going up.

Comment: Does then this curve on the right wraps around the "y-axis"?

Comment: Could you say that differently? I don't think I understood you @Wave

Comment: I mean if this continuous black curve in the right picture turns around the Y-axis like when you wrap a cord around a stick.

Comment: I mean if you do that in a real life stick there is a 3 dimensional aspect going on, here it is 2d, but it does look like that if that's what you are saying @Wave

Comment: ah okey so I see what you mean.