# Is the Riemann Surface really a complex-manifold? Or is it without a point 0?

Tags: complex-analysis, manifolds, riemann-surfaces, complex-manifolds

I just learnt basic complex analysis in school. My teacher simply described the Riemann Surface to explain the multi-valued functions better. I know that the so-called "multi-valued functions" bettwen the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ is actually single-valued functions between the Riemann Surface.

I regard the Riemann Surface as countable infinite many complex planes, cutting the negetive part of real axises, and gluing one side with another plane's another side, according to my teacher's simple description.

To visualize the Riemann Surface, I made my own embedding model of it into $\mathbb{R}^3$, as following:

$\begin{cases}
x=r \cos a \\
y=r \sin a \\
z=ra
\end{cases}\ \ \ \ \ r\geq 0,a\in\mathbb{R}$

One can use Matlab or any tools else to draw it.

If my model is correct, then there is one problem that there is no neighborhood of 0 point homeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}^2$, hence the Riemann Surface is not a complex-manifold unless I throw the 0 point out.

And as I've heard of from my classmates and Wiki, it is a complex-manifold. So there might be something incorrect in my module or in my deduction. Could any one show my fault?

PS: My model without 0 point is the covering space of $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$. And actually I only learnt about the real-manifold detailedly.

Comment: You talk about *the* Riemann Surface as if there is only one. There are many, but you seem to have a specific one in mind. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I thought so. I attend to use one specific Riemann Surface to expain the so-called "multi-valued functions",. You mean there are actually not only one, right? If so I should learn more about it.

Comment: As suggested by the posted answer at time of writing, each different example of a (somehow-natural) multi-valued function would give rise to a Riemann surface (and also a Riemann surface need not arise from thinking about a multi-valued function). So there are many different ones.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your description of infinitely many sheets slit along the negative real axis is consistent with the Riemann surface of $\log$. The half-quasi-helicoid of your parametric equations seems to confirm this, but as you suspect $r = 0$ must *not* be included.

This surface *is* a Riemann surface, a.k.a. one-dimensional holomorphic manifold, which may be viewed as the domain of the complex exponential map, sitting over the punctured complex plane. The point $0$, which is not in the image of $\exp$, is the puncture.

As a side note, you may have better results by using complex variables $w = u + iv$ (with $u$ and $v$ real) and $z = x + iy$ (with $x$ and $y$ real). The graph $z = \exp w$ is parametrized by
$$
(u, v) \mapsto (w, z) = (u, v, e^{u}\cos v, e^{u}\sin v).
$$
This can be converted to a real three-dimensional surface by discarding a coordinate or replacing two coordinates by a real-valued function. A particularly illustrative example (see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1756666/why-does-z-1-not-have-an-antiderivative)) is
$$
(u, v) \mapsto (u + v, e^{u}\cos v, e^{u}\sin v),
$$
which shows both the infinite-sheeted behavior and the logarithmic singularity near $z = 0$.

[image: The Riemann surface of log]

Answer (score 1):

There is not *one* thing called "the" Riemann surface. Riemann surface*s* are a whole class of mathematical objects, just like sets, functions, groups, and manifolds generally.

A Riemann surface most generally is a *one-dimensional complex manifold*, where the "one-dimensional" means a single *complex* dimension, so equivalent to two topological dimensions, i.e. the usual way you think of "dimensions" when you say the surface of a sheet of paper or a globe is two-dimensional. That is, it is a two-dimensional surface which, in some sense, can be considered as a "deformed" complex plane while without compromising its essential geometric features. One of these is *orientability*: a sphere or plane can be a Riemann surface, but a Moebius band cannot, because it in effect would confuse complex numbers with their complex conjugates.

The absence of origin is actually *crucial* to the "manifold" part in this case. What you are missing in the definition of the manifold is not that "every point **in $\mathbb{C}$** has a suitably equivalent neighborhood" but that "every point *on the manifold* has a suitably equivalent neighborhood" to a plane. The origin is *not* on the manifold, so whatever happens there doesn't contradict the definition, and in fact it *cannot* be put on there, because that would indeed break the equivalence: you'd have all the "corkscrew" fanning out from there with a single point floating somewhere along the shaft - it'd not be plane-like *at all* in any set including that point.

Now as I pointed out, the Riemann surfaces are a whole class of objects. This is not necessarily relevant to your immediate example, but it is very important when it comes to "all complex multi-valued functions". In general, there is no *one* Riemann surface that can be used to convert a "multi-valued function" (which I prefer to call a *one-to-many relation*) into a proper function. A good example of a function whose Riemann surface is *different* from the one you cite is the humble square root $\sqrt{\cdot}$. To understand this, consider the following example. Think of starting at $z = 1$ and $\sqrt{z} = 1$, then rotate counterclockwise to $z = i$, taking care you follow a continuous path in $\sqrt{z}$ as well as $z$. Then $\sqrt{z}$ should go to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (1 + i)$. Now rotate to $z = -1$. You should expect $\sqrt{z}$ to go to $i$. Rotate again, to $z = -i$, and $\sqrt{z}$ goes to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (1 - i)$. One more rotation and you're at $z = 1$ again but now $\sqrt{z} = -1$. *Now do another full 360-degree rotation*. You will be at $z = 1$, but also $\sqrt{z}$ has gone back to $1$.

That is, you have arrived, after wrapping twice around the origin, *back to where you started*, whereas on the "parking deck" stack of the surface you give, two rotations just takes you to the third "level", which is separate from the first.

In fact, the Riemann surface of the square root doesn't lend itself to so nice a picture - to embed it into a Euclidean space requires a four-dimensional space, $\mathbb{R}^4$ (or if you like, $\mathbb{C}^2$), and that cannot be visualized in a simple and entirely convincing way because our brains don't work well in that. If you take a projection from $\mathbb{R}^4$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$, it will have a self-intersection, and where that is will depend on the viewing angle of the "camera" or "eye" in $\mathbb{R}^4$. You can think of it as somewhat analogous to a trefoil knot. If you forget about the 3D nature of the object and just pay attention to its 2D projection, you will find the 2D projection intersects itself no matter which way the 3D viewer is oriented, but your brain can make sense out of it instinctively as a coherent, non-self-intersecting object. Since our brains are not set up to visualize 4D naturally, you kind of just have to "take it on faith" the intersection is an illusion.

Riemann surfaces can get even more complicated when we consider that some multi-functions have *multiple branch points*. A good example is $z \mapsto \sqrt{1 - z^2}$. It has *two* branch points at $\pm 1$, for which a small area around each one looks like the square-root Riemann surface I just described.

Comment: I've seen people use (grayscale) color as a sort of proxy for a fourth dimension - so if you can arrange a graph in three dimensions so that the two components at the self-intersection have different colors, then that sort of allows a visualization.

Comment: @Daniel Schepler: Yep, that actually works fairly good, and communicates that the two surface pieces, while they cross through in the projection, are _not_ actually coincident with each other at that crossing point. You can kind of think of such a thing as having a 4D "light source" in the "scene" and illuminating the different parts of the surface nonuniformly, much like a suitably-shaded diagram of the trefoil knot I mentioned.

Comment: (Of course, shading in 4D is a whole topic of its own because only a 3D surface has a proper surface normal; instead, a 2D surface has a surface _binormal,_ i.e. an element of $\mathbb{R}^4 \wedge \mathbb{R}^4$, though a simple and crude method that suffices for these purposes is to just use the _w_-depth [axis perpendicular to the realm of the 3D 'retina'] as shading parameter.)